# How to find reference of file is export by default in vscode?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to find the reference file which is exported by default in vscode?
Key shortcut to find all references in VSCode is: alt + shift + f12
For example: in find data.js

```
async function update(req, res) {
    res.render('update');
}
export default {
    update
}
```

Is there any way to find data.js is imported by another file in VSCode with option find reference as above?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the file on the left panel, you can select find file references